# JTextArea: how to wrap text by words, not characters?

Tags: java, swing, word-wrap, jtextarea

I want to avoid an output like this:

Here is some text t
hat is being wrappe
d by characters, sp
litting words in ha
lf

I am using a JTextArea, with setLineWrap(true). How can I make it wrap words, though? (Is there a way to make it only wrap when there is a space or something?)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`JTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true)`?

Comment: I feel silly for missing this method completely when glancing at the API. Thanks.

Comment: We need to use both the wrapper function together:
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

Answer (score 3):

If you want your text is wrapped by words and not by the characters ( in other words , if you want you half word also shifts to next line

Very simple just use wrapstyleword instead of linewrap
Syntax - JTextArea.setwrapstyleword(true);

Note~ It can only be used when you linewrap is already true 
I hope it would help.

Source ~ My notebook

Credits - 49/51  { 49% to myself & 51% to  my ip teachers Ms. Shalu  }

~ AM 17

Answer (score 3):

You could just go to the properties window of the text field and check the boxes for both wrap style word and line wrap.
It works like a charm

[image: the properties window]

Answer (score 1):

To make wrap by words like this:

```
JtextArea textArea = new JTextArea(8, 20);
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```